# Choose your own adventure! in Bash

Tags: command-line, bash

So I am quite a noob in bash, and I wanted to try and challenge myself with trying to make a choose your own adventure sort of game. I started out trying to use `if` arguments, but that didn't work, so I am trying `case`, and that doesn't seem to work either! here is my script:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 clear
 echo "you are in a dark room."
 echo "1: Turn on light"
 echo "2: Go back to sleep"

 read option1
 case $option1 in
     1) echo "The room fills with light, revealing itself. It is a 
 small room, with a Steel door and a small keyhole. There is a small 
 piggybank with a keyhole and a small wooden chest beside it without a 
 keyhole."
     2) echo "What little of the room you can see fades as sleep 
 washes over you"
     exit 
 esac
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? whenever I try to run this it spits this back at me:

```
/home/sqidman31/Desktop/Test_Folder/Story2.sh: line 10: syntax error 
near unexpected token `)'
/home/sqidman31/Desktop/Test_Folder/Story2.sh: line 10: `   2) echo 
"What little of the room you can see fades as sleep washes over you"'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `case` construct is malformed - each case needs to be terminated by `;;`:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 clear
 echo "you are in a dark room."
 echo "1: Turn on light"
 echo "2: Go back to sleep"

 read option1
 case $option1 in
     1) echo "The room fills with light, revealing itself. It is a 
 small room, with a Steel door and a small keyhole. There is a small 
 piggybank with a keyhole and a small wooden chest beside it without a 
 keyhole."
     ;;
     2) echo "What little of the room you can see fades as sleep 
 washes over you"
     ;;
     *)
     exit
     ;;
 esac
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry guys, I screwed up. I forgot to add an action for the `else` statement, and that screwed it up. false alarm.